# How is XML different from XML schema different from XML?

Tags: xml

How is XML different from XML schema different from XML ?

I read wikipedia, but I am still not clear.
"An XML schema is a description of a type of XML document, typically expressed in terms of constraints on the structure and content of documents of that type, above and beyond the basic syntactical constraints imposed by XML itself."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema

Comment: Please clarify your question.

You are currently doing an XML / XML schema / XML comparison, which makes no sense at all in repeating XML twice.

Comment: http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmlxhtmltutorials/p/what-are-markup-languages.htm

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Nutshell-Third-Elliotte-Rusty-Harold/dp/0596007647/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1354330338&sr=1-3&keywords=XML#reader_0596007647

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-XML-5th-Joe-Fawcett/dp/1118162137/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1354330338&sr=1-2&keywords=XML#reader_1118162137

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`XML Schema` is just like rules or constrains or grammars, which's used to describe what elements should be used in an `XML` document, how these elements are structured. `XML schema` is the blueprint of an `XML` document. I think It's a little bit like the difference between Java class and Java object instance.

For example,

```
`<xs:element name="Company">`
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
          <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
       </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
```

This XML schema defines that, in an XML document, it can only use `Company`, `name`, `address`, `city` and `country` elements, and the `Company` must be the root element.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Company>
  <name>ABC</name>
  <address>Wall Street</address>
  <city>New York</city>
  <country>USA</country>
</Company>
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common analogy between XML and XML schema is given as Architectural Blueprint and actual construction.

Other nice analogy and explanation I come across is 
http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/XML/Schemas_And_XML_Data_Modeling.htm

Hope that helps

Milind